# Slickgrid freeze column issue on vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, slickgrid

I have used SlickGrid in my project. Grid contains 30 columns. Initially grid works fine. it has horizontal as well as vertical scroll. I have frozen first column.
Issue is that when i scroll it horizontally and reached at right most and then after vertical scrolling frozen column data doesn't display. any suggestion please help.

Comment: Please include the exact git repo you are using (I don't believe the master branch has the freeze column feature) and it you can get a [MVP] put together, that would be great

Answer (score 1):

For me this fix works. 
In file slick.grid-frozen-column.js method appendRowHtml.

```
else if (( options.frozenColumn > -1 ) && ( i <= options.frozenColumn )) {
    **appendCellHtml(stringArrayL, row, i, colspan, d);**
    // The d variable is missing
}
```